# SQL insert modified value from one field to a new one

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

my problem here is that I've got no idea of SQL queries but need to do something I'm assuming should not be hard. I've tried some of the recommended questions but I just can't really understand how to extrapolate it to my case, hope you can help me.

Basically what I need is to create some rows in a table, and populate their fields with the
values from other rows in the same table, I'll try to be very specific.

---

I've a got a table ( **vb_postmeta** ) with a lot of rows, some of them look like this:

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1434 | 500 | bpxl_videourl | lOO6hyOKoUM |
| 1435 | 501 | bpxl_videourl | skjd9F008mN |

What I need here is, for each of these rows, to create a new one that look like this:

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUTO | 500 | csco_post_video_url | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOO6hyOKoUM |
| AUTO | 501 | csco_post_video_url | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skjd9F008mN |

**meta_id** is the key, so should auto-generate, while **post_id** should be the same and **meta_value** should also have the same value with the Youtube URL preppended.

I don't really know how hard is this but hope not too much,
thanks in advance for the help, been struggling a lot with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following suggested answers I ended up using this:

```
INSERT INTO vb_postmeta(
    SELECT
        NULL,
        post_id,
        'csco_post_video_url',
        CONCAT('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', meta_value)
    FROM
        vb_postmeta
    WHERE
        meta_key = 'bpxl_videourl'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your meta_id is AI(auto increment) and using mySQL(minor change for MSSQL), try:

```
INSERT INTO vb_postmeta (
SELECT null, 
post_id, 
'csco_post_video_url' 
CONCAT('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=',meta_value
FROM vb_postmeta)
```

Comment: This kind of works, the problem is I should only add a row for each row in the table where  **meta_key** == **bpxl_videourl**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I am assuming you need to insert new rows into the same table - vb_postmeta .

For this,

INSERT INTO vb_postmeta (post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
SELECT
post_id,meta_key,''meta_value
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+NAME
FROM vb_postmeta

Comment: I'm so dumb, I'm using MariaDB not InnoDB, what should I change from your query?